# arcanist install-certificate fails

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I set up my own hosted phabricator, everything is working fine (Diffusion repo etc)

I ran into problem after I installed arcanist on my dev box and run 'arc install-certificate', got exception as following:

rying to connect to server...
LOGIN TO PHABRICATOR
Open this page in your browser and login to Phabricator if necessary:

http:///conduit/login/

Then paste the API Token on that page below.

```
Paste API Token from that page: cli-e644viducdcccrge4i7zo5nfa66d
```

Usage Exception: The token "cli-e644viducdcccrge4i7zo5nfa66d" is not a valid API Token. The server returned this response when trying to use it as a token: ERR-CONDUIT-CORE: Attempting to access attached data on PhabricatorUser (via getAwayUntil()), but the data is not actually attached. Before accessing attachable data on an object, you must load and attach it.

I am wondering what's might go wrong? Thank you very much for your insights!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem occur many times with our users. In every case so far, the problem has been that users have set up the phabricator uri incorrectly.

Suggestion:

- Check your project .arcconfig or your global .arcrc files (if you're doing this outside a project).
- Verify that the URI to your Phabricator site is correct. The typical issue I've seen is accessing using http:// rather than https://

Comment: the cruel thing is that generating the token works with http:// in the config but using the token then fails with very unhelpful messages such as `"Usage Exception: The token "cli-abcabcabc" is not a valid API Token. The server returned this response when trying to use it as a token: ERR-INVALID-SESSION: Session key is not present.`